# How to make a sub folder in hadoop directory which is already created

Tags: hadoop, subdirectory

How to create a sub folder in hdfs directory which is already created

Comment: you should show us what you have tried as this sounds like something that should be covered by documentation. Best regards

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You make it like every other directory

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /path/to/directory
```

With the `p` flag, it doesn't matter if the parent exists